# BIGINT SIGNED vs UNSIGNED

Tags: mysql, database-performance, sqldatatypes

I have production environment 6 GB `MySQL InnoDB` tables with some `BIGINT SIGNED` columns yet the values stored are all greater than `0` and no have chance to be filled with negative values in the future. Will there be a noticeable improved performance if I convert them all or some to `UNSIGNED`? Is there possibility the table will crush during the conversion?

Comment: Better to ask this type of questions on [dba.stackexchange.com](https://dba.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Why would you expect any performance benefits of such conversion?

Comment: @PetSerAl, I don't except anything except a YES or NO answer backed by logical explanation.

Comment: You would be more likely to have a problem with unsigned subtraction of unsigned numbers.  Don't convert now.

Answer (score 4):

Is that single bit really important to you? Performance usually boils down to the fundamental type of data you're manipulating (e.g. `VARCHAR` vs. `INT`) and not sign bits. Just as `VARCHAR(20)` and `VARCHAR(21)` perform basically the same, I'm sure you have a very hard time finding a *measurable* difference in performance between `BIGINT` and `UNSIGNED BIGINT`.

Since `BIGINT` can store astronomically huge values you're unlikely to need that last bit. `INT` can overflow at 2.1 billion, a number some applications are expected to exceed. There's more than 2 billion Tweets, more than 2 billion Facebook posts and so on, but most applications will rarely see even that exceeded.

Don't worry about what you can't measure as a problem. If you think there's a problem, *measure it*. If your measurements are inconclusive you can either try again with a different approach, or resign yourself to the fact that maybe your intuition was wrong.

Computers are ridiculously fast these days and some systems could dump that database into memory and scan through it inside of five seconds. If you're concerned about every nanosecond the first place to start is with the low-hanging fruit, like your indexing strategy or your choice of file system, your MySQL configuration.